# Regular 30 second WiFi dropout from a DrayTek 2926n router

Tags: wireless-networking, connection, draytek

For some months now the WiFi connection to my DrayTek 2926n Router has been awful. Although once-upon-a-time it was OK.

The problem is something to do with the router, as multiple clients exhibit the same problem. And this is just WiFi; wired connections are fine. I've also disabled WiFi passwords, to prove that authentication / encryption is nothing to do with the problem.

Using the linux noping utility you can see the pattern of good and bad connections. Each green bar is a 2 second ping, and exclamation marks a drop in the connection. So roughly every 30 seconds or so the wifi drops, and it is always this consistent.

[image]

There is nothing in the router syslog to indicate a problem.

The laptop is in the same room as the router, who's firmware is up-to-date, and I've turned everything else off to counter interference, and I don't really have any close neighbours who's wifi could be interfering. Plus a different router in the same room doesn't exhibit the problem.

I've tried every helpful suggestion I can find like changing the mode and channel, disabling authentication, etc. But NOTHING changes the pattern of disconnects were are always fairly consistent at every 30 seconds.

Does anyone know what might be going on here? Or can suggest the next thing to try?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obscure solution to this one turned out to be:

1. Downgrade the firmware to the previous version, and
2. Change the wifi channel selection from Auto to stick with channel 1.

This has obviously been a problem since the last upgrade. But only noticed when people started to try video conferencing.

[image: How it should look.]

Comment: Update: the router is still performing OK, but there is a packet-loss rate of about 0.5%. So not perfect, but not really enough to cause a problem.